# Why would a rotor get stuck on the side of the stator when the induction motor is turned on, and how to fix it?

Tags: induction-motor, rotor, stator

My big fan stopped working, so I decided to dismantle it and check what's wrong with it. The problem lies in a faulty induction motor.

I opened it and found out that I can easily turn the rotor inside the stator when the motor is powered off.

Now, as soon as I turn the power on, the rotor get magnetically stuck on one side of the stator. I'm not exactly sure it's always on the same side (I've tried many times).

I checked if one of the 4 coils was not functional using a dangling screwdriver, and it appears all the sides of the rotor get magnetized when powered on.

Would you have an idea of what's going on (and how to fix it)?

Comment: This isn't about static magnetization, the rotor only rotates when there is a phase-shift between the | and the – pole pair (I guess your motor has four *poles*, these are the iron "hands" which embrace the rotor.) You have to check the capacitor which is connected to one of the pairs' coils. That one shifts the phase by 90° and is most likely broken because of old age.

Comment: "stuck" as in rotates but pulls back to that side, or "stuck" as in physical contact? Assuming the latter : worn or broken bearings. If you're lucky, a standard size of bearing, which can be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a capacitor problem, the motor would not start, but it wouldn't "get magnetically stuck." The motor would start when given a "push" by turning the motor or fan by hand when the power is on. That should be done carefully, perhaps using a stick. It should only be attempted with a low power motor.

It is more likely that a bearing is so worn that it is not holding the rotor in position properly. There could also be a problem with the motor housing.

Comment: I solved my problem by doing just that ; 'push' the vertical fan a bit after having cleaned a bit of rust on the motor axis. It turns out the rotor got stuck (physically getting in contact to one side of the stator) when the motor was open, hence the axis was not perfectly aligned. As soon as I closed the motor and the axis was kept in line, the push and a drop of oil got it working again.